# What is the maximum wavelength of the CMB? The minimum?

Tags: cosmology, astronomy, thermal-radiation, cosmic-microwave-background

What are the longest and shortest wavelengths of the cosmic microwave background?

Since it is 'black-body' radiation, does this correspond to max. and min. temperatures?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background#Features seems to answer your question.

Comment: Are you asking about the min/max wavelengths of the CMB that have been *measured*? Theoretically the spectrum of any blackbody includes *all* wavelengths.